# SocketException: Connection refused

Tags: android, flutter, dart

ave created an API using Laravel and I am trying to fetch the data in flutter using HTTP but I keep getting this error.

The error I keep getting in Emulator is **SocketException:Connection refused (OS Error:Connection refused, errno=111), address = 127.0.0.1, port = 41068**

Below is an excerpt of my code.

```
Future<List<Category>> fetchCategories() async {
final http.Response response = await http.get(
  Uri.parse('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/categories'),
);
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  return (json.decode(response.body) as List)
      .map((category) => Category.fromJson(category))
      .toList();
} else {
  throw Exception('Failed to load post');
}
```

}

I added these to android manifest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Fetching the data here

```
   ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
            Category category = snapshot.data![index];
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(category.name),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(
                  context,
                  '/categories/${snapshot.data![index].id}',
                );
              },
            );
          },
        );
```

The android manifest files in both debug folder and the main has internet permission,

I have read this [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51325758/how-to-catch-socketexception-using-the-http-library) but it did not solve the problem

And I have read this as well [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50369768/flutter-http-error-socketexception-os-error-connection-refused)
but none helped

Comment: Did you try curl!?

Comment: I think You've to use ipv4 address.

Comment: How do I go about that? @Gobu CSG

Comment: Check network setting in your server machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because 127.0.0.1 mean the localhost of the current machine which is the android device. Your server is not runing on the android device but the PC machine. You should use the ip address of your PC like 192.168.1.100, and make sure the Android device can access this ip.

Comment: Well, I did as you suggested, I used my device, IP address but it doesn't seem to solve the problem. Am grateful for your suggestion though

Comment: Open the browser on the android device to check if it can access your server first.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. I just checked and realized the emulator can't access it. Can you help on how to go about it? @dante

Comment: You can search how to access host from emulator. I'm not sure I can help you with this.

Comment: The host machine's IP address is 10.0.2.2. Thanks.